# No scroll snap with scroll-snap-type and -align / Simple Example not working Chrome/Firefox /

Tags: css, scroll, scroll-snap-points

Using Chrome / Firefox, I created a container (.container) for a couple of picture (list items with class img). 
I added scroll-snap-type on the container. 
I added scroll-snap-align on the items with class img.

What am I missing here?

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <ul>
  <li class="img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/500"></li>
  <li class="img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/500"></li>
  <li class="img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/500"></li>
  <li class="img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/500"></li>
  <li class="img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/500"></li>
  <li class="img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/500"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.img {
  margin: 10px 5px;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.container {
  display:  grid; 
  justify-content: center; 
  grid-gap: 10px;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this example? - https://codepen.io/maxakohler/pen/JBjROd

Comment: yes, and it works, which is puzzling me as I did nothing different?

Comment: I advise you to fork the pen and do your edits to achieve your desired effect.

Comment: you have missed the opening `<ul>` tag

Comment: doesnt work the opening ul-tag either.

Comment: https://codepen.io/basti-n/pen/YgXgxg => here with div's not working either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it turns out, `scroll-snap-type` requires that you define a height for the container. I am not exactly sure how to explain why it is required, however, defining a `height` does take care of the issue.

```
.img {
  margin: 10px 5px;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.container {
  display:  grid; 
  justify-content: center; 
  grid-gap: 10px;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd read everything and couldn't get it to work correctly until I found your code.

Comment: I think the requirement of defining a height serves to prevent the container from simply accommodating its contents by stretching vertically. If the container is high enough to contain all its children, no need for scrolling. No scrolling, no snapping.

Answer (score 0):

After many tries and exploration (this is 2023) I wanted to leave what worked for me. Sooo, if anyone needs help, this is what worked for me.

1. Don't use `scroll-snap-type: y mandatory`
2. Create element and use `scroll-snap-type: y mandatory` on it
3. In order for `scroll-snap-type: y mandatory` to work you have to add height to that element and also `overflow: scroll`
4. On the children elements (that actually need to snap) you have to add `scroll-snap-align: start;`
5. They do not have to have height specified (at least in my case) but I still put it `100vh` so everything is nice an equal.

Here is a HTML example:

```html
<html>
    <body>
      <div id="container">
          <div class="child"></div>
          <div class="child"></div>
          <div class="child"></div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is CSS code:

```css
#container {
    overflow: scroll;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    height: 100vh;
}
.child {
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Everything is working good now.